# Output nested arrays with id in front of bracket is not output in a correct way

Tags: mysql, node.js, arrays, json, nested

Im trying to combine textContent array for a chat conversation based on user id but the exiting result is not what im looking for, from the @Barman answer instead of sender_user id must be the id of user from "users" table, check my example of code. Im new with this, any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

This is what im trying to achive:

```
 contacts: [
        {
          id: 1 
        },
        {
          id: 2  
        } 
      ],
       
            "chats": {
              userid->  "1": {
                    "isPinned": "true",
                   "msg": [
                        {
                            "textContent": "Hello",
                            "time": "2020-10-07T15:04:40.000Z",
                            "isSent": "true",
                            "isSeen": "true"
                        },
                        {
                            "textContent": "Hello to you, john!",
                            "time": "2020-10-07T15:04:40.000Z",
                            "isSent": "true",
                            "isSeen": "true"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "2": {
                    "isPinned": "true",
                    "msg": [
                        {
                            "textContent": "how are you?",
                            "time": "2020-10-07T15:04:40.000Z",
                            "isSent": "true",
                            "isSeen": "true"
                        },
                        {
                            "textContent": "im fine thx you?",
                            "time": "2020-10-07T15:04:40.000Z",
                            "isSent": "true",
                            "isSeen": "true"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
```

My result based on my exiting code is this, the id "1":{ and "2" must be from getContacts users id, and not from sender_userid:

```
 {
    "chats": {
        "1": {
            "isPinned": "false",
            "msg": [
                {
                    "textContent": "Hello",
                    "time": "Mon Dec 10 2018 07:45:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)",
                    "isSent": "true",
                    "isSeen": "true"
                },
                {
                    "textContent": "im fine thx you?",
                    "time": "Mon Dec 10 2018 07:45:23 GMT+0000 (GMT)",
                    "isSent": "true",
                    "isSeen": "true"
                }
            ]
        },
        "2": {
            "isPinned": "false",
            "msg": [
                {
                    "textContent": "How are you?",
                    "time": "Mon Dec 10 2018 07:45:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)",
                    "isSent": "true",
                    "isSeen": "true"
                },
{
                    "textContent": "Hello to you, john!",
                    "time": "Mon Dec 10 2018 08:45:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)",
                    "isSent": "true",
                    "isSeen": "true"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Mysql chat and users tables :

[image: Mysql chat Database]
[image: Mysql users Database]

Js code:

```
getContacts: (q, callBack) => {
    pool.query(
      'SELECT u.* FROM `users` u INNER JOIN `my_friends` f ON f.myid = u.id WHERE f.friend_id = ? AND f.status = ?',
      [q, 1],
      (error, contacts) => {
        if (error) {
          callBack(error)
        }
        return callBack(null, contacts)
      }
    )
  },
getChats: callBack => {
  pool.query(
    'SELECT * FROM chat WHERE reciever_userid=1 AND sender_userid=5 OR sender_userid=1 AND reciever_userid=5  ORDER BY time', [],
    (error, chats) => {
      if (error) {
        callBack(error)
      }
      return callBack(null, chats)
    }
  )
}

getChats((err, chatz) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return
  }

  getChats: (req, res) => {  
    getContacts((err, users) => {
      getChats((err, chatz) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
          return
        } 
         
        const chats = {}  
        chatz.forEach(({sender_userid, isPinned, textContent, time, isSent, isSeen}) => {
          if (chats[sender_userid]) {
            chats[sender_userid].msg.push({
              textContent,
              time,
              isSent,
              isSeen
            })
          } else {
            chats[sender_userid] = {
              isPinned,
              msg: [
                {
                  textContent,
                  time,
                  isSent,
                  isSeen
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        })
       
        return res.json({ 
          chats
        })
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `SELECT *` if you're just going to delete most of the elements? Just select the columns you want.

Comment: If i do that the output will be messed up... thx for the reply, can u help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Add parentheses to your `WHERE` conditions, because the default precedence of `AND` and `OR` doesn't match your desired grouping.

Instead of modifying the existing `el` object, you need to create new objects so you can combine all the messages for the same sender.

Use `el.sender_userid` as the key in the `chats` property you're creating. And push each chat into the `msg` array if there's already an element with that key.

```js
getChats: callBack => {
  pool.query(
    'SELECT * FROM chat WHERE (reciever_userid=1 AND sender_userid=5) OR (sender_userid=1 AND reciever_userid=5 ) ORDER BY time', [],
    (error, chats) => {
      if (error) {
        callBack(error)
      }
      return callBack(null, chats)
    }
  )
}

getChats((err, chatz) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return
  }

  const chats = {};
  chatz.forEach(({sender_userid, isPinned, textContent, time, isSent, isSeen}) => {
    if (chats[sender_userid]) {
      chats[sender_userid].msg.push({
        textContent,
        time,
        isSent,
        isSeen
      });
    } else {
      chats[sender_userid] = {
        isPinned,
        msg: [{
          textContent,
          time,
          isSent,
          isSeen
        }]
      };
    }
  });

  return res.json({
    chats
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, i see that only the message from sender user appears in the conversation msg, i need to be both messages from me and the sender in the same conversation msg

Comment: Add parentheses to the `WHERE` condition.

Comment: WHERE reciever_userid={1} AND sender_userid={2} like this ?

Comment: See the edit to my answer. It needs to be `(... AND ...) OR (... AND ...)`

Comment: Check these screenshots, to see what im getting now : my values in the db: https://i.imgur.com/ODIq0d1.png - and output from postman: https://i.imgur.com/oPsn6tM.png - i have deleted the id 5 to be only id "2" and me "1"

Comment: What's wrong? You have one message 1->2, and another message 2->1. What else are you expecting?

Comment: Thank you for your reply sorry for taking your time, well to understand what i need is that the message from id 2 needs to be on 1 , they are splitting up, in that output,  message from 1 to 2 and 2 to 1 must be in the same conversation msg, like this example: https://i.imgur.com/St2g9AG.png

Comment: I don't understand the criteria. When do you group them in the same `msg` array, and when do you create a new object with a different `sender_userid` key?

Comment: Well, let me point you in the right direction, please check this github to see all the files, but first see the mock based on my what im trying to achive. : https://github.com/sinaFallahpour/newVuexy/blob/master/admin/src/%40fake-db/apps/chat.js

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help. It doesn't have `receiver_userid` and `sender_userid`. In your desired output, why are the first two messages in the object with userid 1, while the second two objects are in the object with userid 2? Are they both messages between 1 and 2?

Comment: Yes object with userid 2 are both messages between 1 and 2

Comment: Then I don't get it. How do you decide how to group them, if it's not by which one is sender versus receiver.

Comment: i figure'it out why is not ok, i see from the mock that i have send'it to you something, well in fact the "sender_userid"is not ok there, instead of "sender_userid" must be the id from "users" db so the 1: { must be 1 from users table and not from sender_userid. I will edit my question for you, bcz in don;t know to get the user id